# Perl Windows Automation Scripting

Tags: windows, perl, automation

I want to learn it.

Where can I get some good information to start learning?

Comment: What would you like to automate?

Comment: Well there are a couple tasks at the moment I could see myself using this for. One being archiving certain files in certain directories based on their file extension. However I would like to have this talent for other things in the future as well. Import/Export stuff, conversion stuff, etc.

Comment: @Scott : Your question needs to be a lot more focused if you want people to address it effectively. As it stands, the only thing I can recommend is that you take a look at the `Win32::OLE` module.

Comment: Well I was hoping more along the lines of some tutorials and/or books for how to get starting with Windows Automation & Perl (or something similar), but I will check out the Win32::OLE and see what I can make due with.

Comment: You should update your question to say exactly what you want to do, and people will be able to help you much better.

Comment: That's the thing though. I want to learn Perl to Automate Windows. Nothing in specific I just want to know how to use it for Windows Automation purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found [Win32 Perl Programming by Dave Roth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157870216X) quite useful in the past.

It's easy to read and have lots of practical examples.

<sub>Note that it's rather old (2001) and might not be up to date regarding Vista and win7</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What kind of automation?

If you're trying to do things like automate Word or Excel, you should look at Win32::OLE (I think it's called); this lets you use Perl to manipulate these applications as an equivalent to VB/WSH. The ActivePerl install includes a useful tool called "OLE-Browser", which you can use to discover the object model available.

If you're trying to replace .BAT files, you want to use the regular Perl builtin commands for dealing with files and directories (and probably also File::Copy), as well as things like `system()` and `qx()` (which is the function that the backticks are a shortcut for).

Answer (score 0):

The canonical answer to "How do I start learning Perl?" is to get and read [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520113).  It was a classic when I cut my teeth on it a decade ago.  It's been updated a few times since then, but it remains an excellent book.

You might find the book [Perl for System Administration](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926097) useful.  It provides a lot of task oriented examples for Mac, Windows and *nix systems.

If you are looking for free/online resources, you can find a directory at [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org).